# Ask Ubuntu election page is unavailable during current election

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, error-message, 500-server-error

Currently there's a moderator election ongoing on Ask Ubuntu, with the nomination phase closing in about one day. Unfortunately, right now the https://askubuntu.com/election page is broken and temporarily redirects with status code 302 to https://askubuntu.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/election (code 500), making it impossible to see or do anything related.

I hope this bug can be fixed as soon as possible. You might also consider extending the nomination period by the time span the page has been down.

Comment: Well... that's no good. Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: @Catija looks like it's fixed.

Comment: Had to do with a nominee having two accounts merged. It's fixed for this case.

Comment: @Catija Yeah, it works again, thanks. Would you post an answer so that the issue can be marked as solved?

Comment: I'm going to leave it for Adam to explain after he fixes it. :) it's not quite fixed yet.

Comment: @Shog9 Will the election period be extended as a result of this outage?

Comment: There are 8 days left for voting, @Sonic. Unless someone plausibly intended to nominate and wasn't able to, there's no reason to alter the schedule.

Comment: @Shog9 Okay, that makes sense.

Comment: @Catija is Shog the new Adam? ;)

Comment: I think we all have [a bit of the Old Adam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Adam), eh @Shadow?

Comment: @Shog9 or byte, yeah. ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The root of the problem here is that the election system doesn't handle situations where users involved in the election are deleted. At least, it doesn't handle them *well*.

In this case, one of the candidates was merged - effectively, their profile was deleted and information moved to a new user with a new ID... While the old ID persisted in the election data.

The short-term fix here was to just update the ID. The medium-term fix is to correct the logic that blows up when a user can't be found. The long-term fix would be to automatically update IDs when a candidate is merged or deleted.